# citation inside a caption don't follow order of appearance

Tags: citing, natbib

citations inside a caption of a figure don't follow the order of appearance in the document. I used this in the preamble

```
    \usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

and this when I included the figure

```
     \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]  
      {images/Fluid_distrubution_and_wettability}
     \caption{Wettability and fluid distribution at pore level
     \protect\cite{Crain68:online}}.
     \label{fig:wett.fluid.dist}
    \end{figure}
```

But then I get for example Figure 2.2, caption here `[1]` even though I have already many citations before the figure. But if I put this code in other areas of the document, citations are exactly according to the order they appeared in the document.

Comment: `\usepackage{notoccite}% PREVENTS CITES IN CAPTIONS FROM MISNUMBERING YOUR REFERENCES`  The problem arises because the caption citation shows up in the list of figures/tables, which, unless intercepted, gets incorporated into the citation order.  The `notoccite` package does the interception for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[converting my comment to an answer...]

The problem arises because the caption citation shows up in the list of figures/tables.  Any citations in those "list-of-xxx" captions, unless intercepted, get incorporated into the citation order. The `notoccite` package does the interception for you.

```
\usepackage{notoccite}% PREVENTS CITES IN CAPTIONS FROM MISNUMBERING YOUR REFERENCES
```